# PDO, check for empty string and don't update if empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I run my function `edit_profile()` without any parameter, then empty strings are written in DB. If `$input['email']` is empty for example, I'd like `UPDATE` not to update this column.

I tried to do:

```
SET email = IF(LENGTH(:email)=0, email, :email),
```

It didn't work, I'm not sure how to do same as above with PDO.

```
function edit_profile($input) {
    //
    $user_id = 1;
    //
    try {
    //

        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET
                                    email = :email,
                                    password = :password,
                                    name_surname = :name_surname,
                                    age = :age,
                                    sex = :sex,
                                    education = :education,
                                    avatar = :avatar
                                    WHERE id = :id');


                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':id'           => $user_id,
                    ':email'        => $input['email'],
                    ':password'     => $input['password'],
                    ':name_surname' => $input['name_surname'],
                    ':age'          => $input['age'],
                    ':sex'          => $input['sex'],
                    ':education'    => $input['education'],
                    ':avatar'       => $input['avatar']
                ));


        echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
    //
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    //
}
edit_profile();
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown he'd like update not to update this column

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown You really don't understand? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE users SET
email = COALESCE(NULLIF(:email, ''),email),
password = :password,
name_surname = :name_surname,
age = :age,
sex = :sex,
education = :education,
avatar = :avatar
WHERE id = :id
```

I'm basically trying to use COALESCE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to use `:email` only if not null. If it's null, use the old `email`.

In case `:email` is empty string and not simply `NULL`, I've added `NULLIF` to convert the empty string to `NULL` ;)

Comment: Awesome! I like coalesce :)

Comment: @Marek, could be that you are right - did not check. I updated my answer with a possible workaround. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET email = IF(LENGTH(:email1)=0, email, :email2)

$stmt->execute(array(
                ':id'           => $user_id,
                ':email1'        => $input['email'],
                ':email2'        => $input['email'],
                ':password'     => $input['password'],
                ':name_surname' => $input['name_surname'],
                ':age'          => $input['age'],
                ':sex'          => $input['sex'],
                ':education'    => $input['education'],
                ':avatar'       => $input['avatar']
));
```